# when redis update, redis will send the update to my grpc server. How to implement it

Tags: redis

When there's an update in redis, redis would send the update to my grpc server. How to implement it.

It looks like redis monitor command can get all updates in redis. I though I can parse data from redis monitor and send it to grpc server.
Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you want to notify when your value get updated in `redis`. If so, you can use redis `keyspace notification` to get notified about update. You need to subscribe this event, so `redis` will publish when ever update done. So you need to use any one of clients like node.js to subscribe those events, so you can do whatever you need from there.

You can get detailed explanation from following page with this example:

Reference: https://redis.io/topics/notifications

**FYI:** By default this notification will be disabled, if you want then you need to enable by update redis configuration and **restart is needed to apply this configuration change**.